# Rails migrations on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if Rails is capable of doing migration on the fly without locking table.
For example, there are too many tools that can do this [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) and [oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html). Therefore it's reasonable to assume that it's already done, are you familiar with something like this?

Comment: It's not Rails that locks your table, it's the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I just answered another similar question. You should look into https://github.com/DAddYE/mini_record

It works very similar to Datamapper. Just define or modify your column names/types right in your model and the schema gets updated automagically. Pretty cool.

I'm not sure about the locking, but you can submit an issue on that github page. The developers are very responsive and helpful.